# Move Button Frame During Animation

Tags: animation, swift, uibutton, uiviewanimation

I am using the below code in my keyboardWillShow method which triggers when the keyboard will show. I know the code is running using debug, but there is no change to the button frame. When the print first runs, the origin.y is 471. When it runs on completion, it is still 471.

What I'm attempting to do is animate this button to appear and move up with the keyboard. It is to be used as a DONE button for textviews.

kbHeight is 253.

animateDuration is 0.25.

Numbers.ANIMATE_DELAY is 0.0

```
//Animated done button with keyboard
    origDoneFrame = btnDone.frame
    btnDone.hidden = false
    println(self.btnDone.frame.origin.y)
    var uConverted:UInt = UInt(animateCurve)
    var options = UIViewAnimationOptions(uConverted << 16)
    UIView.animateWithDuration(
        animateDuration,
        delay: Numbers.ANIMATE_DELAY,
        options: options,
        animations: {
            println(self.btnDone.frame.origin.y)
            println(kbHeight)
            println(self.btnDone.frame.origin.y-kbHeight)
            self.btnDone.frame = CGRectMake(self.btnDone.frame.origin.x, self.btnDone.frame.origin.y - kbHeight, self.btnDone.frame.size.width, self.btnDone.frame.size.height)
            println(self.btnDone.frame.origin.y)
            return Void()
        },
        completion: {finished in
            println(self.btnDone.frame.origin.y)
            return Void()
        }
    )
```

The output returns as below:

```
471.0
471.0
253.0
218.0
218.0
471.0
```

The button has constraints on it, which is the only thing I can see that would reset it back to the bottom, but I'd rather ignore the constraints when I manually change the frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ignore the Autolayout constraints in a way. It's not so much ignoring as removing them completely. Using the below code, you can accomplish this:

```
//Set up done button
        btnDone.removeConstraints(btnDone.constraints())
        btnDone.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(true)
        btnDone.frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.size.width - btnDone.frame.size.width - 8, view.frame.size.height - btnDone.frame.size.height - 8 + self.tabBarController!.tabBar.frame.size.height, btnDone.frame.size.width, btnDone.frame.size.height)
        btnDone.alpha = 0.0
        btnDone.hidden = true
```

From this point forward, you can move the button about as needed. This does cause a warning occasionally regarding satisfying multiple constraints, but the button behaves as expected.

Answer (score 0):

> but I'd rather ignore the constraints when I manually change the frame.

You can't. Autolayout doesn't work like that. You have to modify the constraints instead, otherwise the view just gets repositioned during the auto layout pass.

Create an outlet to the constraint that is giving the button its vertical position, modify the `constant` property, and call `view.layoutIfNeeded()` in your animation block.